# I thought TCP sent packets in order?

Tags: php, c++, python, tcp, irc

I am sending the following in a IRC bot:

```
bot->message("chanserv", "op #channel");
bot->raw("KICK #channel " + this->nick(args[0]) + " :RIPIP");
sleep(2000);  // even tried sleepin
bot->message("chanserv", "deop #channel");
```

I see it sent across the socket

```
PRIVMSG chanserv :op #channel
KICK #channel baduser :RIPIP
PRIVMSG chanserv :deop #channel
:hobana.freenode.net 482 username #channel :You're not a channel operator
```

But then it spits back a packet saying you're not an operator, *then* the op/de-op response packets.

Comment: Please don't spam multiple language tags...

Comment: Sounds like a buffering issue in the server.

Comment: I am compiling php into c++ with hiphop and then using embedded python for the plugins

Comment: Is bot->mesage buffered and bot->raw unbufferred? I'd be *very* surprised if TCP packets are being *sent* out of sequence but even if they are, as long as the data enters the stream in the ocrrect order it will come out in the same order. Have you checked with a packet sniffer?

Comment: Making a bigot of myself, TCP "packets" are not really "send". IP packets are. Maybe out of order. And are reassembled and re-ordered to produced a stream of data on the receiver side. AFAIK, you cannot read "out of order" TCP stream. Are you sure you are using TCP and not UDP here?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have anything to do with TCP - it's related to the architecture of IRC.  The `ChanServ` service is not generally part of the client ircd that you are connecting to.  It is instead implemented by a seperate ircd that is linked to the client ircd(s).

This means that your `KICK` (from your client) can arrive at your client server before the mode change message that ops you (from the services daemon) is arriving.

To do this properly, you need to issue the `op` command to `ChanServ`, then wait until you see the `MODE` command giving you ops before issuing the `KICK` and `deop` commands.